# Drupal 7 Custom module with different theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I have been asked to build a custom landing page / section of an existing Drupal 7 site via a custom module but the section needs to have a design that is completely different than that of the parent site. It's just a full size background image, no navigation, no footer, no header, and a new form.

Can you remove all the base site theme from a 'page' via custom module so you can create a custom design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes you can! It would require a lot of work, but you can.

**Long answer:** If the requirement about the solution coming from a custom module is strict, then skip to the last part of this answer. Otherwise you're welcome to fully read it.

**What I would do**

If the requirement about `custom module` is not strict, you can just create a page and add a custom template for it. Take a look at [Template (theme hook) suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions)

i.e. Create a page called `My custom page` and let's say the Node id is **23**, so you can create a file called `page--node--23.tpl.php` inside the current theme.

In that page you can modify all the html you need (even the header, footer, etc.)

**Custom module**

If the solution above does not work for you, you'll have to:

1. Create a custom module
2. Create a custom theme

In the custom module you can add a new path like this:

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['my-page-path'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_render_page',
  );
  return $items;
}
function mymodule_render_page() {

  // Render your content
}
```

Later use the [hook_custom_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_custom_theme/7.x), in the module, to load your custom theme when certain criteria is met.

Something like:

```
<?php
function mymodule_custom_theme() {
  if ($criteria_is_true) {
    // Use the machine name of your custom theme
    return 'my_custom_theme';
  }
}
```